# Undefined reference Linker error to a variable already in the same file

Tags: c++, windows, g++, linker-errors

I am making code for linked lists and I've been getting this weird error when I try to compile with g++.

```
/cygdrive/c/Users/Blas/AppData/Local/Temp/ccEcixjp.o: In function `Node':
/cygdrive/c/Users/Blas/Documents/blas.borde/trunk/Cs170/Lab6/List.h:50: undefined               
reference to 'CS170::ListLab::Node::nodes_alive'
/cygdrive/c/Users/Blas/Documents/blas.borde/trunk/Cs170/Lab6/List.h:50: undefined               
reference to 'CS170::ListLab::Node::nodes_alive'
/cygdrive/c/Users/Blas/Documents/blas.borde/trunk/Cs170/Lab6/List.h:56: undefined               
reference to 'CS170::ListLab::~Node::nodes_alive'
```

And this is my code

```
namespace CS170
{
  namespace ListLab
  {
    struct Node
    {
      int number;             // data portion
      Node *next;             // pointer to next node in list
      static int nodes_alive; // number of nodes still around

      // Non-default constructor
      Node(int value)
      {
        number = value;
        next = 0;
        nodes_alive++; // a node was created
      }

      // Destructor
      ~Node()
      {
        nodes_alive--; // a node was destroyed
      }
    };
  }
}
```

The weird thing is that i am already defining nodes_alive so I don't know why the linker says that the variable is not defined. Maybe there is something obvious that I am missing.
Please, I need help.

Comment: Where do you define `nodes_alive`? It's a static member variable, so you *declare* it inside the struct, but you must *define* it outside.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It seems that you only declared static data member node_alive in the class definition but not defined it outside the class. In some module in the global namespace write

```
int CS170::ListLab::Node::nodes_alive;
```

or

```
namespace CS170
{
   namespace ListLab
   {
      int Node::nodes_alive;
   }
}
```

Though it will be implicitly initialized by zero you can explicitly specify 0 as an initializer in its definition.